# Can't su to user other than root on CentOS

Tags: centos, sudo, su

I'm able to SSH to my server (CentOS 5.9) using an admin account with sudo privileges:

```
$ ssh admin@myserver
Last login: Wed Feb 27 19:23:11 2013 from [IP ADDRESS]
[admin@myserver ~]$
```

Then I can su to root:

```
[admin@myserver ~]$ sudo su root
[sudo] password for admin: 
[root@myserver admin]#
```

But I can't su to another user, and the su command is not telling me why:

```
[admin@myserver ~]$ sudo su anotheruser
[admin@myserver ~]$ whoami
admin
```

Any idea why I can su to root, but not to other users?

How can I get su to tell me why it is not doing what I want it to do?

Comment: Don't use `sudo`, just `su`. Try `su root`, then `su user` as root. Then for more details, try `su user` as admin.

Comment: @Chloe `sudo su anotheruser` most certainly can work.  It just needs to be granted in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: (Reason being is that it may not be desirable to know the target user's password. Sudo allows you to authenticate as yourself.)

Comment: Why don't you just give those users permission to run commands as the other users in `/etc/sudoers` and forget this unnecessary indirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What permissions are granted in `/etc/sudoers` to `admin`?

Also, as `root`, you could always `su - anotheruser`. An extra step perhaps, but without knowing anything about your sudoers file this will work.

Comment: My permissions in /etc/sudoers look like this:

`root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL`
`%admins ALL=(ALL)       ALL`

The admin user is in the admins group.

Comment: You're going to need to look in `/var/log/secure`, then. Sudo / su log to the authpriv facility which generally goes to `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: I would double (triple) check the group membership of admin user. Is it a local group or domain? Try adding the user by name to `/etc/sudoers` to test and eliminate a point of failure.

Comment: That's great feedback. I can see the su command working from admin to root in the /var/log/secure, but I find this for the admin user trying to su to anotheruser:

`Feb 28 10:03:38 myserver su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user anotheruser by admin(uid=0)

Feb 28 10:03:38 myserver su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user anotheruser`

I'm still not exactly sure what's going on except that it's opening a session and then immediately closing the session.

Comment: I've also added the admin user to the sudoers file just below root like this: `admin ALL=(ALL) ALL`. Still no luck.  The root user is also not able to su to another user account--not just the admin.  I can, however, su from root to admin and vice-versa.

Comment: I think something has been changed in PAM to deny this. Default settings permit it. (I've tested it on a workstation here.) Try verifying your `/etc/pam.d/su*` files with `rpm -V sudo` and `rpm -V coreutils`. (Look for `/etc/pam.d/su*` files in particular.) If you have another box load it up with a clean install and test there.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like after adding the `admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` to the sudoers file did the trick after all.  I'm not sure why it wasn't working at first (maybe the settings were cached).  It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 12):

In case it's useful to someone else: I just ran into the same symptoms but the answer had nothing to do with `sudo` configuration.

Instead, it mattered which *user* I was trying to `su` to.  The target user was a service pseudo-user (jenkins) which had /bin/false as its shell.  The fix was to change the shell to a valid one (using `chsh`).

Answer (score 3):

Check `/var/log/security` and `/var/log/auth.log`.

Why are you using `sudo` to use `su`?  You don't need to do that unless you change your standard ACLs.

If you use `sudo`, then the issue might be related to you sudoer file.  Verify you have it configured properly.

Comment: Reason to use `sudo su` over `su` is to use his own password instead of the target user.

Comment: Also, these logs don't exist in a default CentOS 5.9 installation.

Comment: On my other server (similar setup) by using sudo, I'm able to su using my own password.  When I su by itself with no sudo, it says "incorrect password".

Comment: `su` by itself requires you to use the target username's password, not your own.

Comment: Is it a specific user you're having issues with or all users other than root?  Also, can you show your sudoer's file?